# using multiselect dropdown and looping through its values using jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, multi-select

I have a multiselect drop down, on selecting multiple items from it,  i need to pass the value of this multiselect into an ajax file, and create divisions dynamically and load the data retreived from the ajax files into these dynamic divisions.

```
var itemvalues= [];

$('#MultiSelectItemID :selected').each(function(i, selected) {

itemvalues[i] = $(selected).val();

                });


$('#itemContent').html(LoadHTML);       
        $('#itemDetailsContainer').fadeIn('',function(){                    
        $('#itemContent').load('ajax_calls/item_details.php?ItemID='+$('select[name=MultiSelectItemID]').val() || [], 
        function(){
                    $(this).show('highlight');      



                    });     });
```

Now , i want to loop through each value in the itemvalues[] array and pass it to my php file and get the data and load it into a new division.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Will this do the job? (Note I 've changed "MultiSelectItemID" to simply "ItemID" and `serialize()`d it.)

http://jsfiddle.net/svzsY/8/

```
    var itemvalues = [];
    $('#itemContent').html(LoadHTML);
    $('#itemDetailsContainer').fadeIn('', function() {
        $('#itemContent').load('ajax_calls/item_details.php', ($('select[name=ItemID]').serialize() || []), function() {
            $(this).show('highlight');
        });
    });
```